# Qual é a diferença entre o dump-autoload normal e o otimizado, no Composer?

Tags: composer

No composer é possível fazer a geração automática do autoload através do comando `composer dump-autoload`.

Porém também é possível gerar um "autoload otimizado" através do comando `composer dump-autoload -o`.

Gostaria de saber qual é a diferença entre eles?

Do que se trata essa otimização do Composer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

O `-o` ou `--optimize` converte o PSR-0/4 para o classmap pra poder obter mais rapidamente as classes no autoloader. Isto é altamente recomendado principalmente em servidores de produção, a otimização pode levar algum tempo a mais.

*Fonte: https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#dump-autoload*

Quando não usamos o `-o` ele mantem dividido as classes nos arquivos:

- `composer/autoload_files.php`
- `composer/autoload_namespaces.php`
- `composer/autoload_psr4.php`
- `composer/autoload_files.php`

E a maioria dos objetos é detectado conforme o PATH baseado no namespace em tempo de execução, então pra cada classe com namespace terá que fazer a checagem de path e arquivos, porém ao usar o `-o` ele mapeia todos namespaces e classes diretamente para uma array dentro do `autoload_classmap.php`, em um projeto que tenho com Lumen tem ~45kb, isso porque teu tenho PHPUnit e algumas outras dependências pro ambiente de desenvolvimento.

Já após usar o `-o` ele fica com ~206kb e passa a ter todas "classes possíveis" já mapeadas:

```
<?php

// autoload_classmap.php @generated by Composer

$vendorDir = dirname(dirname(__FILE__));
$baseDir = dirname($vendorDir);

return array(
    'App\\Console\\Kernel' => $baseDir . '/app/Console/Kernel.php',
    'App\\Events\\Event' => $baseDir . '/app/Events/Event.php',
    'App\\Events\\ExampleEvent' => $baseDir . '/app/Events/ExampleEvent.php',
    'App\\Exceptions\\Handler' => $baseDir . '/app/Exceptions/Handler.php',
    'App\\Http\\Controllers\\Controller' => $baseDir . '/app/Http/Controllers/Controller.php',
    'App\\Http\\Controllers\\ExampleController' => $baseDir . '/app/Http/Controllers/ExampleController.php',
    'App\\Http\\Middleware\\Authenticate' => $baseDir . '/app/Http/Middleware/Authenticate.php',
    'App\\Http\\Middleware\\ExampleMiddleware' => $baseDir . '/app/Http/Middleware/ExampleMiddleware.php',
    'App\\Jobs\\ExampleJob' => $baseDir . '/app/Jobs/ExampleJob.php',
    'App\\Jobs\\Job' => $baseDir . '/app/Jobs/Job.php',
    'App\\Listeners\\ExampleListener' => $baseDir . '/app/Listeners/ExampleListener.php',
    'App\\Providers\\AppServiceProvider' => $baseDir . '/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php',
    'App\\Providers\\AuthServiceProvider' => $baseDir . '/app/Providers/AuthServiceProvider.php',
    'App\\Providers\\EventServiceProvider' => $baseDir . '/app/Providers/EventServiceProvider.php',
    'App\\User' => $baseDir . '/app/User.php',
    'Carbon\\Carbon' => $vendorDir . '/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/Carbon.php',
    'Carbon\\CarbonInterval' => $vendorDir . '/nesbot/carbon/src/Carbon/CarbonInterval.php',
     ...

     [total de 1815 classes mapeadas]
```

Desta maneira se tiver muitas classe pra carregar em uma requisição isto pode ajudar a poupar certas execuções que o SPL iria fazer pra encontrar o arquivo correspondente a classe, mas é bom notar que em alguns casos isso pode ter um efeito colateral contrário ao esperado.

Comment: Bem, isso já é uma informação importante. Porque `optimize` ficou meio vago: "Otimizar o quê?"... Agora dá pra entender

Comment: @WallaceMaxters consegui formular um exemplo :)