# Erro ao importar classe com use

Tags: php, slim

A estrutura das minhas pastas e arquivos está assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O que eu estou tentando fazer sem exito, é utilizar a classe Validacao.php no Usuario.php

Para isso eu utilizei o comando `use Classes\Validacao;`

**Usuário.php**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Validacao.php**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Mas recebo sempre este erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Estou utilizando o framework slim

Comment: Como você está declarando a chamada da classe Validação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O tal "classes" precisa estar no `composer.json`, PHP não consegue adivinhar aonde se localiza e o `use` não é igual ao `include` como expliquei em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/151492/3635

O composer (que o Slim usa), faz uso do `spl_autoload` que esse sim "programa" os seus scripts para localizarem as classes, no caso o composer usa o `composer-autoload`, então é preciso adicionar ele no seu `composer.json`, assim:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Slim\\": "Slim",
        "Classes\\": "Classes"
    }
},
```

O `Classes\\` é o prefixo para indentificar pelo namespace, e o `"Classes"` é a pasta aonde estão localizadas, deve ficar semelhante a isto:

```
{
    "name": "slim/slim",
    "type": "library",
    "description": "Slim is a PHP micro framework that helps you quickly write simple yet powerful web applications and APIs",
    "keywords": ["framework","micro","api","router"],
    "homepage": "https://slimframework.com",
    "license": "MIT",
    "authors": [
        {
            "name": "Josh Lockhart",
            "email": "hello@joshlockhart.com",
            "homepage": "https://joshlockhart.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Andrew Smith",
            "email": "a.smith@silentworks.co.uk",
            "homepage": "http://silentworks.co.uk"
        },
        {
            "name": "Rob Allen",
            "email": "rob@akrabat.com",
            "homepage": "http://akrabat.com"
        },
        {
            "name": "Gabriel Manricks",
            "email": "gmanricks@me.com",
            "homepage": "http://gabrielmanricks.com"
        }
    ],
    "require": {
        "php": ">=5.5.0",
        "pimple/pimple": "^3.0",
        "psr/http-message": "^1.0",
        "nikic/fast-route": "^1.0",
        "container-interop/container-interop": "^1.2",
        "psr/container": "^1.0"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "squizlabs/php_codesniffer": "^2.5",
        "phpunit/phpunit": "^4.0"
    },
    "provide": {
        "psr/http-message-implementation": "1.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Slim\\": "Slim",
            "Classes\\": "Classes"
        }
    },
    "scripts": {
        "test": [
            "@phpunit",
            "@phpcs"
        ],
        "phpunit": "php vendor/bin/phpunit",
        "phpcs": "php vendor/bin/phpcs"
    }
}
```

Depois de adicionar no composer.json execute o comando:

```
composer dump
```

Ou então execute o comando `composer update` se desejar que além de atualizar as classes ele também baixe as dependências do Slim e outros pacotes que você adicionou

Assim estará disponivel no composer-autoload

---

### Leia mais sobre composer

O básico:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Alguns links úteis em português de respostas que formulei:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/139916/3635
- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/123131/3635
- [Como criar o meu próprio package para composer no github?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/100158/3635)

Comment: Exatamente isso!!! Muito obrigado

Comment: Se você quer apenas fazer o Composer gerar os autoloaders de classes, não use `composer update`, mas apenas `composer dump`. O `composer update` vai fazer uma varredura por novas versões, o `composer dump` vai apenas trabalhar em cima dos autoloads

Comment: @WallaceMaxters opaa!!! Verdade, atualizando!