# namespace php7 não acha url?

Tags: php, php-7, namespace

Estou tentando aprender `namespace` mas estou tendo dificuldade.

Mesmo fazendo exatamente como está em um vídeo no youtube, mas não dá certo.

Tenho a pasta do projeto

```
Projeto
Projeto\Cadastros
Projeto\Cadastros\Index.php
Projeto\Cadastros\Pessoa
Projeto\Cadastros\Pessoa\Pessoa.php
Projeto\Cadastros\Teste
Projeto\Cadastros\Teste\Pessoa.php
```

Index.php

```
<?php

 ini_set("display_errors",true);
 ini_set("display_startup_erros",1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL && E_NOTICE);
 error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT ); // PHP 5.3
 error_reporting( E_ALL ); // Todas as outras versões 

 $pessoa = new Pessoa(1, 40, "Carlos");

 $pessoa2 = new Pessoa2();
 $pessoa2->setIdPessoa(1);
 $pessoa2->setIdadePessoa(43);
 $pessoa2->setNomePessoa("Cleonice");


 echo $pessoa->getIdPessoa()."<br >";
 echo $pessoa->getNome()."<br >";
 echo $pessoa->getIdadePessoa()."<br >";

 echo "<br />";

 echo $pessoa2->getIdPessoa()."<br >";
 echo $pessoa2->getNomePessoa()."<br >";
 echo $pessoa2->getIdadePessoa()."<br >"; 


?>
```

Pessoa.php

```
<?php

namespace Cadastros\Pessoa\Pessoa;

Class Pessoa {

    private $idPessoa;
    private $idadePessoa;
    private $nome;

    public function __construct ($_idPessoa, $_idadePessoa, $_nome) {
        $this->idPessoa = $_idPessoa;
        $this->idadePessoa = $_idadePessoa;
        $this->nome = $_nome;
    }

    public function getIdPessoa () {
        return $this->idPessoa;
    }

    public function getIdadePessoa () {
        return $this->idadePessoa;
    }

    public function getNome () {
        return $this->nome;
    }
}


?>
```

Pessoa.php

```
<?php

namespace Cadastros\Teste\Pessoa;

Class Pessoa {

    private $idPessoa;
    private $idadePessoa;
    private $nomePessoa;

    public function __construct () {}


    public function setIdPessoa ($_idPessoa) {
        $this->idPessoa = $_idPessoa;
    }   

    public function setIdadePessoa ($_idadePessoa) {
        $this->idadePessoa = $_idadePessoa;
    }   

    public function setNomePessoa ($_nomePessoa) {
        $this->nomePessoa = $_nomePessoa;
    }

    public function getIdPessoa () {
        return $this->idPessoa;
    }

    public function getIdadePessoa () {
        return $this->idadePessoa;
    }

    public function getNomePessoa () {
        return $this->nomePessoa;
    }
}


?>
```

Erro

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'Pessoa' not found in C:\Program Files\Apache24\Apache24\htdocs\funerariasaopedro.net.br\Cadastros\index.php:19 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\Program Files\Apache24\Apache24\htdocs\funerariasaopedro.net.br\Cadastros\index.php on line 19
```

O que está de errado?

Comment: É use Cadastros\Pessoa\Pessoa;

Comment: Not found também!

Comment: Além do namespace esta errado, está falando incluir o arquivo!

Comment: Olha só. Além de ter o namespace ainda precisa fazer o require_once ""? O namespace não faz isso não? Então o namespace é só para fazer trabalho duplicado. Se eu precisarei mesmo assim fazer o include do arquivo, então né melhor fazer só o include. Ou entendi errado o conceito de namespace?

Comment: O seu namespace eu faria assim por exemplo na classe Pessoa colocaria `namespace Projeto\Cadastros` e utilizaria `use Projeto\Cadastros\Pessoa` e precisa trabalhar com include, require ou até um auto_load, tem bastante resposta sobre isso aqui no site só pesquisar!

Comment: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.oop5.autoload.php e https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php-autoload

Comment: em outras palavras: fazer 2 trabalhos em um só: o include e o namespace. Salvo entendi errado! Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Teu PHP simplesmente não faz nada, `use` não é como `import` do Java ou `using` do C#, ele não é um `include`, ele é apenas uma parte da linguagem para referenciar um "namespace" com um apelido.

Como eu expliquei em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/151492/3635

O correto seria usar `spl_autoload_register` (ou outras das funções da SPL para este proposito), como já respondi em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/88039/3635

---

Agora se estiver usando `composer` (eu disse "se estiver"), então você deve incluir o composer-autoload no teu `index.php`, pois só assim ele vai conseguir identificar as classes pelos namespaces e resolve-las, claro que é necessário configurar o `composer.json` também, como eu já respondi em:

- https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/304591/3635

Se o intuito é usar composer, então leia mais sobre ele em:

- https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md
- https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

---

### [Extra] sobre os erros no PHP

Esta parte aqui esta provavelmente errada:

```
 ini_set("display_errors",true);
 ini_set("display_startup_erros",1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL && E_NOTICE);
 error_reporting( E_ALL | E_STRICT ); // PHP 5.3
 error_reporting( E_ALL ); // Todas as outras versões
```

Simplesmente configurar no php.ini já resolveria, se for produção então nem use isto, só para desenvolvimento, fora que `display_startup_erros` realmente tem uma intenção diferente do que você provavelmente esta imaginando e aplicar `error_reporting` não irá ter efeito, fora que o intuito do `error_reporting` é bem mais do que exibir erros, leia isso:

- [Por que usar error_reporting com display_errors e display_startup_errors?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/106562/3635)